# Walk Cycle Loop at 0|0|0, not from A to B

Tags: animation, unreal-engine

For a propererly working walk cycle in UE4 I need my character not to move from A to B, it has to loop at 0|0|0. I use a bvh file as my walk animation, my character is imported from makehuman.

It should look like this in the end:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rLBCg_LAN4
(NSFW, video contains a nude character, but it is the best one I found to describe my problem/goal)

Thank you for your knowledge and time!